# How to get rid of double faces on my mesh?

Tags: vertices, edges, faces

[image]

[image]

I want it to look the same as this side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider

- using Mesh/Cleanup/Limited Dissolve.  Mesh Menu in Edit Mode.
- using a Mirror Modifier to keep both sides exactly the same.  This means you would delete one side, right or left and let the modifier keep the sides in correspondence.  The modifier can merge the middle vertices.
- Delete the loop ring.  Then Bridge Edge loops on the two open loops which need to be closed. This is on the Edge menu.

Comment: Wow, it was easier than I thought. The first one worked, thanks.

Comment: Of course its easy.  The fun is just starting. 

Answer (score 1):

Alt + M > Select "By Distance" will Merge Vertices that are very close to each other/share the same coordinate. You can also change the distance for this in the bottom left corner of your screen.

Alternativly, if you've accidentally created two identical meshes sharing roughly the same space, you can select one part of your mesh and hit CTRL + L to select everything that's connected to it.

Since you want both sides to look identical, you can also select all faces on the side that looks fine and delete the rest. Then select the faces again and press Shift + D to create a copy of them. Move them where you'd like to have them and select the outer rings of your two planes with Alt + Left Mouse button. Now hit F3 and search for "Bridge Edge Loops"

Comment: F3. Good..  You might also add vertex slide or edge slide then remove  doubles, which is similar to your first paragraph.